# Chrome on Android: my text runneth over

Tags: support, design, mobile-web, accessibility

Yesterday I started noticing some odd spacing on some but not all SE sites in the mobile web site on Chrome (54.0.2840.85) on Android (4.4.4).  Take a look at this screen shot from Workplace meta:

[image: Workplace: extra space near "all questions"]

There's plenty of room for "All Questions" plus the search icon to fit there, but instead we get line-wrap.

On some other sites this doesn't happen:

[image: Mi Yodeya is fine]

The mobile web site doesn't account for custom site designs, so I don't think this is coming from some quirk of Workplace (and some other sites).  Every site I've visited behaves consistently across visits; while I can't discern a pattern to *which sites* are affected, it appears that a site's behavior in this regard doesn't vary.

At the same time, the paging buttons in chat started being affected:

[image: chat buttons are funky]

In the accessibility settings I have the minimum text size set to 105%.  That's *just slightly bigger* than the baseline (100%), and there's plenty of space there to lay out these elements differently, and this only just started happening.  If I change that setting back to 100% the problem goes away, but then I end up having to zoom more pages, which means horizontal scrolling (a much worse UX than text-only zoom).

I'd like to get this fixed without having to abandon this accessibility setting.  I understand that at some text sizes things just don't fit, but here there's room -- can we be more flexible?